# Mod_rewrite in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, qtranslate

I've got an url /nl/sunglasses which is a translated page by qtranslate. I want to change this to /zonnebrillen . I prefer not to change this in wordpress since the 'sunglasses' is generated by a plugin wp-ecommerce and hardcoded.
Can I use a mod_rewrite so that /nl/sunglasses will be /zonnebrillen. And how can I let wordpress 'know' to show the according page?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I modified after getting WP to take query vars in the URL including "name" as a query var. I am including the "original" .htaccess file posted by regular WP install to show the context. I have separated the rewrites to avoid problems when WP updates, or when "certain admin functions" cause it to change. P.S. I didn't test this, but similar code works for a much more complex page redirect... so try it. Let me know if it doesn't work for you, I'll test it.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^nl/sunglasses/ /zonnebrillen [NC,L]
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Should work with WP 3.4+